# Selecting multiple entries from XML with same name WP7

Tags: c#, xml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, linq-to-xml

I have tried for several hours and searching on the net for examples on how to pull multiple elements with the same name however different attributes and binding those to my XAML in my app for wp7,

the easiest way for me to explain is to simply show you,

heres what I have so far

```
       public class Match
    {
        public string HomeTeam { get; set; }
        public string AwayTeam { get; set; }
        public string HomeScore { get; set; }
        public string AwayScore { get; set; }
        public string GoalsPlayer { get; set; }
        public string goal { get; set; }
        public string GoalsTime { get; set; }
        public string DismissalsPlayer { get; set; }
        public string DismissalsTime { get; set; }
        public string BookingPlayer { get; set; }
        public string BookingTime { get; set; }
        public string GameTime { get; set; }
    }

 void wc_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        XElement element = XElement.Parse(e.Result);
        try
        {
            listBox2.ItemsSource = from item in element.Descendants("competition")
                                   from match in item.Elements("match").Where(arg => arg.Attribute("awayTeam").Value == team | arg.Attribute("homeTeam").Value == team)
                                   select new Match
                                   {
                                       HomeTeam = (string)match.Attribute("homeTeam"),
                                       AwayTeam = (string)match.Attribute("awayTeam"),
                                       HomeScore = (string)match.Attribute("homeTeamScore"),
                                       AwayScore = (string)match.Attribute("awayTeamScore"),
                                       GoalsPlayer = (string)match.Attribute("playerName"),
                                       GoalsTime = (string)match.Attribute("time"),
                                   };
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
             Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
        }
```

here is my XAML

```
<ListBox Name="listBox2" Grid.Row="0">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Name="teams" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding HomeTeam}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding HomeScore}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding AwayTeam}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding AwayScore}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Name="scores" Orientation="Horizontal">
                                    <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding GoalsPlayer}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                                    <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding GoalsTime}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                                </StackPanel>
                                <StackPanel Name="dismissals">
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DismissalsPlayer}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
                                    <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="{Binding DismissalsTime}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

here is my XML

```
<match homeTeam="Arsenal" awayTeam="Liverpool" homeTeamScore="0" awayTeamScore="2">
<goal time="77:13" playerName="Aaron Ramsey" />
<goal time="89:57" playerName="Luis Suarez"/>
<dismissal time="69:59" playerName="Emmanuel Frimpong"/>
</match>
```

I understand that I will only get one entry on my Page for Goals, which would be the first goal element in my XML

how can I go about that and implement every

```
<goal ...>
<goal ...>
```

into my Datatemplate that currently only shows the first entry, another potential problem is I cannot guarantee how many goals there will be so I am a really unsure on how to go about it entirely

thanks

John

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you're actually trying to achieve? I'm not clear on your last 2 paragraphs.

Comment: Sorry, of course, my databinding only shows the first entry for <goals ...> on my Page, I believe its because I only process one entry, and I am unsure how to show every <goal ...> entry on my page.

Comment: currently the page only shows the entry for Aaron Ramsey, and does not show for Luis Suarez

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should `playerName` even resolve on your `match`? Because that's where you are resolving it in your XML query.

Regardless, what you are looking for here is a sub-object that can be held in a list property of the `Match` object:

```
listBox2.ItemsSource = from item in element.Descendants("competition")
                       from match in item.Elements("match")
                           .Where(arg => arg.Attribute("awayTeam").Value == team || 
                                         arg.Attribute("homeTeam").Value == team)
                       select new Match
                       {
                           HomeTeam = (string)match.Attribute("homeTeam"),
                           AwayTeam = (string)match.Attribute("awayTeam"),
                           HomeScore = (string)match.Attribute("homeTeamScore"),
                           AwayScore = (string)match.Attribute("awayTeamScore"),
                           Goals = match.Elements("goals").Select(ev => new MatchEvent
                           {
                               Player = (string)ev.Attribute("playerName"),
                               Time = (string)ev.Attribute("time")
                           }).ToList(),
                           Dismissals = match.Elements("dismissals").Select(ev => new MatchEvent
                           {
                               Player = (string)ev.Attribute("playerName"),
                               Time = (string)ev.Attribute("time")
                           }).ToList(),
                       };
```

And the updated XAML:

```
<ListBox Name="listBox2" Grid.Row="0">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
             <StackPanel Name="teams" Orientation="Vertical">
             <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                  <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding HomeTeam}"/>
                  <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding HomeScore}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                  <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Text="{Binding AwayTeam}"/>
                  <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding AwayScore}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
              </StackPanel>
              <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Goals}">
                  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <StackPanel Name="scores" Orientation="Horizontal">
                              <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Player}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                              <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                          </StackPanel>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              </ItemsControl>

              <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Dismissals}">
                  <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                      <DataTemplate>
                          <StackPanel Name="scores" Orientation="Horizontal">
                              <TextBlock Margin="0,10,0,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Player}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                              <TextBlock Margin="10,10,30,0" Foreground="White" Text="{Binding Time}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" />
                          </StackPanel>
                      </DataTemplate>
                  </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
              </ItemsControl>
          </StackPanel>
      </DataTemplate>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Comment: Could you please explain how this works, also MatchEvents I assume will be a new class? how will I bind a list to a single Textblock entry in my DataTemplate?

Comment: Yes playerName should as I need the name of the person who scored,

Comment: `MatchEvent` is a separate class that generalizes goal and dismissal. You cannot bind a list to a TextBox, you'll have to add a child `ItemsControl` into your `ItemTemplate` and bind _its_ `ItemsSource` to the `MatchEvents` property.

Comment: Thank you Richard thats awesome, Really appreciate your input

Comment: After reviewing your question, I've split up Goals/Dismissals into separate objects/lists. I've also added the updated XAML to better explain the nested ItemsControl.

Comment: I added <DataTemplate> between <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> and <StackPanel> as it was giving me an error

Comment: @John - Thanks, I've fixed it in my answer too :)